# React doesn't rerender on props change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have following code, and the goal is to prepare some object for ajax POST operation.
So actually I have several `<input/>`, providing pieces of data for some object. I just simplified it to be short and understandable.

```
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
    onChange (value) {
       var newValue = this.props.value;
       newValue.field = value;
       this.props.dispatch(setValue(newValue));
    },

    render: function () {
      return (
        <myOtherComponent>
           <div><input onChange={this.onChange}/></div>
           <div>this.props.value</div>
        </myOtherComponent>
              )
    }
});
```

Also I have an action:

```
export function setValue(value) {
    return {
        type: 'VALUE',
        data: value
    }
};
```

And reducer, which contains:

```
case 'NEW_DOCTOR':
            return {
                ...state,
                value: action.data
            };
```

The problem is that when I do `this.props.dispatch(setValue(newValue));`, though I see in `console.log` that reducer is definitely fired, the `<myOtherComponent>` doesn't rerender. So I have to put `this.setState(this.state)` after `this.props.dispatch(setValue(newValue));`, then it rerenders. I see this behavior second time, and really cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. Any clues?

Comment: what's in your myOtherComponent? And why don't you include the divs inside "myOtherComponent"?

Comment: @QoP For this problem it doesn't really matter. `myOtherComponent` is just some shared component with `{this.props.children}` somewhere inside, where I want to put some custom elements for different purposes. It's basically composition paradigm used in React apps development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure this is the cause of your problem, but inside this piece of code:

```
onChange (value) {
  var newValue = this.props.value;
  newValue.field = value;
  this.props.dispatch(setValue(newValue));
},
```

You are directly mutating props, which you shouldn't.

Since `newValue = this.props.value`,
the statement `newValue.field = value`
also mutates `this.props.value`.

Comment: You are right, thank you, I found the same after reading some articles.